# Are there any books which specifically deal with the laws of an Aguna? Preferably in English?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, books-generally

I know where it is written in the Torah that a man needs to write a document for his wife in order to divorce her, but I want to know if there is a thoroughly explained book written on the topic of Aguna laws.

I'm looking for discussions about pressuring recalcitrant husbands to give a get, what kinds of evidence is needed to believe a husband died, ways to annul a marriage retroactively, and what monetary rights a wife has to her recalcitrant husband's property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rabbi Breitowitz's book: Between Civil & Religious Law: The Plight of the Agunah in American Society](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0313284717)

And later, [Rabbi Broyde's: Marriage, Divorce, and the Abandoned Wife in Jewish Law](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881256781)

Comment: By the way -- Rabbi Broyde wrote his book in the late 90s, and included something to the effect of "the old-fashioned Agunah -- where the husband disappears at sea and we have little evidence to prove his death -- doesn't happen anymore." Then 9/11 happened and Rabbi Broyde had to pasken a handful of such cases.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://koltorah.org/ravj/Agunot%201.htm) is a good resource for learning this topic.